# Split while loop into multiple parts

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

I want to wrap every 10-groups of items in a while-loop inside a wrapper.
Visualized:

```
echo "<ul class='wrapper'>";

while(get_field('items'))
{
    echo "<li>item</li>";
}

echo "</ul>";
```

In this case every element would be inside this one wrapper, but I have to wrap at max ten elements and then start a new wrapper.
What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```
$count=1;    

echo "<ul class='wrapper'>";
while(get_field('items'))
{
    if($count % 10 == 0) {echo '</ul><ul class='wrapper'>';}
    echo "<li>item</li>";
    $count++;
}

echo "</ul>";
```

Answer (score 1):

A different way to do this is:

```
<?php
$count = 0;
$group = array();

while(get_field('items'))
{
    array_push($group, "<li>$val</li>");
    if(++$count % 10 == 0)
    {
        echo "<ul class='wrapper'>".implode("", $group)."</ul>";
        $group = array();
    }
}
?>
```